# ant 'unless' on a macrodef

Tags: java, ant, build, dependencies, macrodef

I'd like to write a macrodef that depends on the property being set in another macrodef, such as this, which doesn't work... (macrodef doesn't support depends and unless attributes) Anyway to do this?

```
<project name="mac">

    <property name="antlr.version" value="3.2"/>

    <macrodef name="check">
        <attribute name="dest"/>
        <attribute name="name"/>
        <attribute name="version"/>
        <sequential>
            <available file="@{dest}/@{name}-@{version}.jar" property="@{name}-exists"/>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <macrodef name="pull" depends="check" unless="@{name}-exists">
        <attribute name="url"/>
        <attribute name="dest"/>
        <attribute name="name"/>
        <attribute name="version"/>

        <sequential>
            <get src="@{url}" dest="@{dest}/@{name}-@{version}" verbose="true" ignoreerrors="true" unless="@{name}-exists"/>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="pullall">
           <pull url="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr/${antlr.version}/antlr-${antlr.version}.jar" dest="." name="antlr" version="${antlr.version}"/>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
    <project name="mac">

        <property name="antlr.version" value="3.2"/>
        <property name="stringtemplate.version" value="4.0.2"/>

        <target name="check">
            <available file="${dest}/${name}-${version}.jar" property="jar-exists"/>
        </target>

        <target name="_pull" depends="check" unless="jar-exists">
            <get src="${url}" dest="${dest}/${name}-${version}.jar" verbose="true" ignoreerrors="true"/>
        </target>

        <macrodef name="pull">
            <attribute name="url"/>
            <attribute name="dest"/>
            <attribute name="name"/>
            <attribute name="version"/>

            <sequential>
                <antcall target="_pull">
                    <param name="url" value="@{url}"/>
                    <param name="dest" value="@{dest}"/>
                    <param name="name" value="@{name}"/>
                    <param name="version" value="@{version}"/>
                </antcall>
            </sequential>
        </macrodef>

        <target name="pullall">
        <pull url="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr/${antlr.version}/antlr-${antlr.version}.jar" dest="." name="antlr" version="${antlr.version}"/>
        <pull url="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/stringtemplate/${stringtemplate.version}/stringtemplate-${stringtemplate.version}.jar" dest="." name="stringtemplate" version="${stringtemplate.version}"/>
        </target>

</project>
```

Comment: The nice thing about macrodef is that it could be used in the outer scope (before targets), this solution does not consider that.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this question is a "bit" older this may help someone:

with ant 1.9.1 the if:set unless:set attributes where introduced.
https://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html

this way you can use your macros as follows (tested with ant 1.9.3)

```
<project name="mac" xmlns:unless="ant:unless">

    <property name="antlr.version" value="3.2"/>

    <macrodef name="check">
        <attribute name="dest"/>
        <attribute name="name"/>
        <attribute name="version"/>
        <sequential>
            <available file="@{dest}/@{name}-@{version}.jar" property="@{name}-exists" />
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <macrodef name="pull">
        <attribute name="url"/>
        <attribute name="dest"/>
        <attribute name="name"/>
        <attribute name="version"/>

        <sequential>
            <check dest="@{dest}" name="@{name}" version="@{version}" />
            <get src="@{url}" dest="@{dest}/@{name}-@{version}.jar" verbose="true" ignoreerrors="true" unless:set="@{name}-exists" />
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="pullall">
           <pull url="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr/${antlr.version}/antlr-${antlr.version}.jar" dest="." name="antlr" version="${antlr.version}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

btw. there are other tricks with macros and if:set/unless:set too, see here http://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2013/09/13/using-ifset-unlessset-etc-with-macrodefs-in-ant/

You can even simulate a conditional macro if you add the if/unless to the sequential body of the macro.